# Drupal 7 field validation with database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal.

I have a form and it contains only one field, which is text field. Now corresponding to that field some data is there in SQL SERVER database now when I enter any value it has to check, whether the value which user has entered is there in the database field or not.

Kindly help me out. As I did a lot of searching related to it. but didn't got any solution...

I have tried client side validation module didn't succeeded.

https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your form (`hook_form_alter`) by adding a validation function:

`$form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_email_form_validate'`;

or

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'my_module_email_form_validate';
```

After this you'll be able to validate any form data in:

```
function my_module_email_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  form_error($form, t('Your error.'));
}
```

Comment: down vote accept
 

Thanks Sir,

But do i need to create a separate module for this,

and how should i write the code.

kindly tell me the pattern of the code as well sir.....

will it check in the database whether the field is containing the right data or not. dont i need to write sql query for checking it in database

i have a form named cancellation and one field is there named as ticket number.....

kindly help as on priority...

Thanking You.

Comment: OK, let's start from begin. Where is from your form with one field. Provided by some contrib module?

Comment: sir i didn't get that.

Comment: sir i read it but didn't got any conclusions related to the validation